# JS Слияние двух массивом в один по id?

Tags: javascript

Привет всем есть два таких массива объектов

```
const array1 = [ 
{ "id": 1, "name": "12 годин", "price": "", "checked": false }, 
{ "id": 2, "name": "24 годин", "price": "", "checked": false }, 
{ "id": 3, "name": "48 годин", "price": "", "checked": false }, 
{ "id": 4, "name": "Без видалення", "price": "", "checked": false }, { "id": 5, "name": "Репост", "price": "", "checked": false } ]
```

И вот второй массив

```
const array2 = [ 
{ "id": 1, "name": "12 годин", "price": 100 }, 
{ "id": 2, "name": "24 годин", "price": 400 } 
]
```

Мне надо как то объединить (слить) их в один массив объектов если id = id, причем если есть поле price, то "checked": true.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать (

Comment: Самый простой — пройдите с помощью цикла, скопируйте данный из одного массива в другой.

Comment: `причем если есть поле price` -- У какого объекта вообще должна проводиться проверка на существование свойства `price`?

Comment: `Мне надо как то объединить (слить) их в один массив объектов` создать новый или мутировать текущий?

Comment: Покажите, какой массив на выходе вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 0):

> Мне надо как то объединить (слить) их в один массив объектов если id = id, причем если есть поле price, то "checked": true.

Предложу такой вариант

```js
const array1 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "12 годин",
    "price": "",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "24 годин",
    "price": "",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "48 годин",
    "price": "",
    "checked": false
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Без видалення",
    "price": "",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Репост",
    "price": "",
    "checked": false
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "12 годин",
    "price": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "24 годин",
    "price": 400
  }
]

array2.forEach(o2 => {
  const i = array1.findIndex(o1 => o1.id === o2.id)
  if (i === -1) return
  array1[i].price = o2.price
  array1[i].checked = !!o2.price
})
console.log(array1)
```